# Table in latex/Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

How can I make a table like this in Latex?[image]

Here is my simple solution.

```
\newcommand\TS{\rule{0pt}{3.5ex}}
\newcommand\BS{\rule[-2.3ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\vspace{2mm}
%\begin{table}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{cyan!10}}c}
\begin{tabular}{|g|c|c|c|c|c|}%{p{1in}p{1in}p{1in}p{1in}}
\hline
x i mm\quad \TS \BS \ & \quad \TS \BS $6$ \quad \TS \BS & \quad \TS \BS $10$ \quad \TS \BS & \quad \TS \BS $11$ \quad \TS \BS& \quad \TS \BS $15$ \quad \TS \BS& \quad \TS \BS $20$ \quad \TS \BS \\
\hline
y    \quad \TS \BS  & \quad \TS \BS $300$ \quad \TS \BS & \quad \TS \BS $200$ \quad \TS \BS & \quad \TS \BS $110$ \quad \TS \BS & \quad \TS \BS $89$ \quad \TS \BS& \quad \TS \BS $60$ \quad \TS \BS\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the compilable TeX code you have tried so far!

Comment: Well I know how to make simple tabel, The problem is to make these zig zag line.

Comment: Take a look at `NiceMatrix` which lets you use `TikZ` machinery.

Comment: @RoseWhite, welcome. Can you please complete your code to make life easier for all of us? Just follow these simple steps: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: If your question is how to make this zig-zag line, I suggest that you put this information into your question (in the title even). This would make your question unique and stand out from lots of other questions.

Answer (score 6):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the zigzag lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
 {
   custom-line = 
    { 
      letter = Z , 
      tikz = { decorate , decoration = zigzag }
    }
 }

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|m{4cm}|c|cZw{c}{1cm}Zc|c|}
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-6}
Antal år efter 1970 & 0 & 1 & ... & 39 & 40 \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-6}
Produktion af palmeolie (tusinde ton) & 217 & 250 & ... & 19324 & 21958 \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-6}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]